# Как извлечь данные из docker volume на windows 10

Tags: docker

Решил запустить mongodb из контейнера. Пытался запустить командой `docker run -v D:\Desktop\mongo\db:/data/db -d mongo` но позже прочитал, что сделать это на windows не возможно, тогда я создал volume командой `docker volume create testdb` и запускал контейнер командой `docker run -v testdb:/data/db -d mongo`, все запустилось, но как теперь извлечь данные из созданного volume и где он вообще находится?

Comment: командой `docker cp`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Windows, Docker запускается на виртуальной Linux-машине.
Скопировать файлы в/из контейнера (для которого вульюм подключен как /data/db) можно командой `docker cp`, но, обычно работа этой команды ограничена папкой `C:\Users` или она вообще не работает.

В качестве альтернативы, можно запустить контейнер с SFTP и открыть нужную папку через WinSCP (https://winscp.net/eng/download.php):

```
docker run \
    -v testdb:/home/foo/testdb \
    -p 2222:22 -d atmoz/sftp \
    foo:pass:1001
```

И подключиться через WinSCP указав

- хост: свой IP адрес
- порт: 2222
- логин: foo
- пароль: pass

Может быть проблема с правами доступа, так как пользователь mongodb может иметь отличный от 1001 идентификатор.

Comment: Ваша информация [несколько устарела](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/#download-docker-for-windows) -- для Windows уже существует нативный докер поверх Hyper-V.

Comment: Мало кто включает Hyper-V в ущерб VMWare и прочим. А решение с SFTP будет работать на чем угодно.